# Magento 2 change product attributes before saving

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, event-observer, configurable-product

I have used the catalog_product_save_before event like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_before">
        <observer name="Ziffity_SkuRelation_Observer" instance="Ziffity\SkuRelation\Observer\Configurable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

I can able to get product data which is been posted to the save controller by the below code.

```
$_product = $observer->getProduct();
```

Also, I can able to change data before saving it like below.

```
$_product->setData('name','custom-name');
```

But what I need is before saving I have to check whether it's a configurable product. Then if it's a configurable one then I have to change attributes to its child simple products alone. When I check conditions like this below.

```
if($_product->getData('type_id') === 'configurable'){
     // Inside this condition I can't get it's simple product data.
}
```

Inside the above condition, I can't get its simple product data.
I need to update data if a configurable product is created and to its simple product please support.

Also, I have tried using the save after method like below.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productIds = [];
        $attributes = explode(",",$this->data->getAttributes());        
        $_product = $observer->getProduct(); 
        $flag = $_product->getData('enable_relation_flag');
        $type = $_product->getTypeId();        
        if($type === 'configurable'){
            $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);            
            $productIds['parent'] = $_product->getId();
            foreach ($_children as $key => $child){
                $productIds[]['child'] = $child->getId();
            }
        }
        if(!$flag){
            foreach($productIds as $ids){
                if(isset($ids['child'])){
                    $product_id = $ids['child'];
                    $productFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
                    $product = $productFactory->create()->load($product_id);
                    foreach($attributes as $attrs){
                        $product->setData($attrs,'');
                        $product->save();                        
                    }                    
                }                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried this $_product->getProductType(); ?

Comment: I'm getting product type id by  $_product->getProductType(); and also by $_product->getData('type_id') but I need to change attributes only for simple not for configurable. If I check like above I said in my question I can't update data to simple one.

Comment: Add in the answer what you are doing to update the product so far

Comment: For example, when a user creates a configurable product the description given will be saved for its child products too. But I need to stop the same configurable product description to save on simple products. So I have to check whether the user-created configurable and update to child products.

Comment: Can you not use save after, and at that time update the description of simple product to blank? Just another approach.

Comment: I have tried like this using save after event but child products are not created
See my updated question